# ASP.NET Alert box from Class

Tags: asp.net

I'm using a class "Service" to connect to a DB and return a DataTable to my ASP.NET page.

I'm using try/catch to catch SqlExceptions. I want to display the exception text to the user in an Alert box. How do I do this?

This is my function in Service.class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace Classes
{
    public class Service
    {
        private static DataTable getDataTable(string query)
        {
            DataTable dt = null;
            SqlConnection con = Dao.getConnection();
            if (Dao.checkConnection())
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
                dt = new DataTable();
                try
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Response.Write("<script>alert('This is Alert');</script>");
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write();
                //ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), " ","alert('ERROR')", true);
                //var clientScript = Page.ClientScript;
                //clientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(null, "AlertScript", "alert('ERROR')'", true);
                //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Database error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

The compiler gives me this: 
    The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context.

I guess it's pretty basic, just haven't been able to find the answer yet.
The commented stuff is what I tried so far!

Comment: Return a result to the ASPX caller and display the alert properly from the UI using [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)? A business/data object shouldn't be writing to the response stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.response.aspx) as the Response you are looking for is available under class inheriting from System.Web.UI.Page

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<script>alert('This is Alert');</script>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + String Exception message + "');", true);
```